# Can't get text to append to jtextarea

Tags: java, append, jtextarea

I am trying to create a console like function for some software. I have the output formatted as I want but only for console output using System.out.println. I am trying to get some form of text in the jtextarea. I have tried using .`setText()` and `.append()` yet had no lucky with either. I was wondering if anyone could help me spot why it's not working? My application uses 2 forms, Any help is appreciated as always..

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2(); 
     f2.openMe(comboOne.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

form2 code is as follows:

```
public void openMe(String message) {

    System.out.println("Console Output");
    System.out.println("---------------------------");
    System.out.println("Printer selected: "+ message);
    System.out.println("\n");

    //ta.setText(message);
    ta.append("hi");


}
```

Comment: Where do you declare the `ta` object? Also are you getting any error?

Comment: @DCruz22 It's my first time using a GUI builder rather than just swing coding from scratch, this has been generated at the bottom of the code;

     // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea ta;
    // End of variables declaration        

Also not getting any error..

Comment: And where do you call this method?

Comment: in public void openMe on form2 @DCruz22